# Use socket.io inside a express routes file

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to use Socket.io with Node.js and emit to a socket within the logic of a route.

I have a fairly standard Express 3 setup with a server.js file that sits in the route, and then I have an index.js which sits in a routes folders that exports all the pages/publically accessible functions of the site. So they look like:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: "Awesome page"
    });
};
```

with the routing defined in server.js like:

```
app.get('/',routes.index);
```

I'm assuming I have to create the socket.io object in the server.js, since it needs the server object, but how can I access that object and emit to it from the index.js export functions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can set up your routes file as a function, and pass the Socket.IO object when requiring the file.

```
module.exports = function(io) {
  var routes = {};
  routes.index = function (req, res) {
    io.sockets.emit('payload');
    res.render('index', {
      title: "Awesome page"
    });
  };
  return routes;
};
```

Then require routes like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var routes = require('./routes')(io);
```

Comment: Alright, that does require a bit of refactoring. I'd hope there'd be a cleaner way

Comment: This solution is good, but if you want to see a similar approach that a bit cleaner and intuitive check out this answer I found by Logan Tegman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872317/express-4-routes-using-socket-io

Comment: Your method utilizes dependency injection, and I like it over the global state var solutions.

Answer (score 147):

There is a better way to do this now with Express 4.0.

You can use [app.set()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table) to store a reference to the `io` object.

**Base configuration:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
// next line is the money
app.set('socketio', io);
```

**Inside route or middleware:**

```
exports.foo = function(req,res){
    // now use socket.io in your routes file
    var io = req.app.get('socketio');
    io.emit('hi!');
}
```

Information about `app.set()` and `app.get()` is below:

> **app.set(name, value)**
>
> Assigns setting name to value. You may store any value that you want,
>   but certain names can be used to configure the behavior of the server.
>   These special names are listed in the [app settings table](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table).
>
> Calling `app.set('foo', true)` for a Boolean property is the same as
>   calling `app.enable('foo')`. Similarly, calling `app.set('foo', false)`
>   for a Boolean property is the same as calling `app.disable('foo')`.
>
> Retrieve the value of a setting with `app.get()`.

Source:  https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set

Comment: I'd really love a second opinion on using app.set() to store a reference like this. It would be a sweet way to do it if it is sturdy.

Comment: I took pattern from socket.io API doc at the time, check it out now maybe is different way

Comment: yea, I don't think they mention it in the docs are any alternative. But it looks super slick.

Comment: Someone already used this aproach? I have issue with it. When page reloads or socket reconnects all emits by the socked twiced, thriced and so on... there is no workaround about this (either i can't find). It's seems to be inpossible to use socketio with express routes

Comment: Can this be applied for `socket.broadcast.emit` (rather than `io.emit`)?  If so, how can you access `socket`?

Comment: This worked for me using socketio and express together

Comment: @aarosil Thanks for your help. I have tried your solution, and it works for io.emit() but not for io.on(). I have posted a new question here if you wanna have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274727/io-sockets-on-not-working-inside-a-route-in-node-js

Comment: @marcvander you can't listen inside of one endpoint you only can listen on app.js or server.js but you can emit inside the routes file

Answer (score 26):

aarosil's answer was great, but I ran into the same problem as Victor with managing client connections using this approach. For every reload on the client, you'd get as many duplicate messages on the server (2nd reload = 2 duplicates, 3rd = 3 duplicates, etc).

Expanding on aarosil's answer, I used this approach to use the socket object in my routes file, and manage the connections/control duplicate messages:

**Inside Server File**

```
// same as aarosil (LIFESAVER)
const app = require('express')();
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
// next line is the money
app.set('socketio', io);
```

**Inside routes file**

```
exports.foo = (req,res) => {

   let socket_id = [];
   const io = req.app.get('socketio');

   io.on('connection', socket => {
      socket_id.push(socket.id);
      if (socket_id[0] === socket.id) {
        // remove the connection listener for any subsequent 
        // connections with the same ID
        io.removeAllListeners('connection'); 
      }

      socket.on('hello message', msg => {
        console.log('just got: ', msg);
        socket.emit('chat message', 'hi from server');

      })

   });
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Worked like a charm

Comment: It's not working for me.

Answer (score 10):

Super late addition here, but I wanted to access a socket in my routes and specifically wanted to broadcast a message after saving to the database.  I used the answer provided by @aarosil to set/get the io object, sent the each client its socket id on connection, then used the socket id in the route to be able to use `socket.broadcast.emit()` instead of `io.emit()`.

In server:

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
app.set('socketio', io)

io.on('connect', socket => {
  socket.emit('id', socket.id) // send each client their socket id
})
```

I send the socket id with each req and then I can do the following in my routes:

```js
router.post('/messages', requireToken, (req, res, next) => {

  // grab the id from the request
  const socketId = req.body.message.socketId

  // get the io object ref
  const io = req.app.get('socketio') 

  // create a ref to the client socket
  const senderSocket = io.sockets.connected[socketId]

  Message.create(req.body.message)
    .then(message => {

      // in case the client was disconnected after the request was sent
      // and there's no longer a socket with that id
      if (senderSocket) {

        // use broadcast.emit to message everyone except the original
        // sender of the request !!! 
        senderSocket.broadcast.emit('message broadcast', { message })
      }
      res.status(201).json({ message: message.toObject() })
    })
    .catch(next)
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Whats wrong with just using

```
global.io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: Works. Feels too hacky.. but it's probably the simplest solution especially if you'll need to access the io object outside handling requests or middleware.

Comment: This is an outstanding solution that deserves more credit for ease of use.  Works especially well when using express-generator and having logic spread across multiple files.

Answer (score 3):

In Server file,

```
    const app = express();
    const server = require("http").createServer(app);
    
    const io = require("socket.io")(server);
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      app.set("socket", socket);
    });
```

Inside any controller,

```
     const socket = req.app.get("socket");
     socket.emit(customerId, { test: "something" });
```

Comment: Modern and Functional 

Comment: This wont work!

Answer (score 0):

`module.parent.exports.server` would also work if you exported server in the parent module.