# Socket.io in Express routes file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I'm working on a project which consists in creating a game of the goose like. In order to do that, I'm using Node.js, Express, jade and now Socket.io. But I encounter some trouble, like, in example, to share the position of one client to the other client. Because my variable position is in a function in index.js and I don't know how I can use Socket.io in a route file. I try some things, but nothing works.

On internet, I've seen some people who say that there is no-sense to use Socket.io in an express route file. So how can I do that ?

In my index.js I've that :

```
exports.deplacement = function(io)
{
    return function(req,res)
    {
            //[...]
            io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) 
        {
               socket.broadcast.emit('position', space);
        });
res.render('moteur' //[...]);
    }
}
```

And in my moteur.jade I've done this :

```
 script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
 script.
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
  socket.on('position ', function(space) {
    alert(space);
  })
```

Comment: What do you mean by using socket.io in a route file?

Comment: Hmm, when you use Express your js files are stored in a route folder and you access to them in app.js with the line app.get('/smthing', routes.something);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use socket.io inside a express routes file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856190/use-socket-io-inside-a-express-routes-file)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure what your question exactly means, but if it is what I think it is then I think what you mean by using socket.io in a route file is to be able to include the client side javascript lib provided with socket.io module of Node.

In order to do that, you have to allow the socket.io module to listen to server. This works like a middle-ware itself. Everything has to go through socket.io first before they are routed to the server. So, when you request the client side lib, it is uploaded to the client.

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
```

Comment: What I mean is actually to use Socket.io in another js file than app.js in order to pass data from my function which is in index.js to the client.

Comment: Well! One thing you can do is try to use a callback in some socket.io handler which works outside of your routes folder. You can then import it in your route file.