# Using socket.io in routes other than server/app.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, routes

Hi I am trying to use socket.io in a file other than my main **server.js** file where I first set it up like so:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

Since I am setting it up in my server.js file I have to listen for events in this file and therefore the callback function will only have access to the scope of this file. However I need to use this in another file in my routes that I have set up like so for example:

```
app.use('/', home);
```

I have read both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310942/socket-io-in-express-routes-file%22this%22) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870304/using-socket-io-in-routes) and neither one has helped me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your socket logic in another file inside a function and call it from server.js.

**socket.js**

```
const io = require('socket.io');

module.exports = function(server) {
io(server).on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
}
```

and in **server.js**

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require("./socket")(http)
```

Comment: Never thought of that simple way. Thank you.