# Send messages from server (Expressjs routing) to client

Tags: javascript, express, npm, websocket, socket.io

I want to send messages from the server to the client and **implement this in `routes/index.js`** of my mean stack project. Does anyone know how to use `socket.io` here?:

```
router.post('/message/sendMessage', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("router.post /message/sendMessage " + req.body)
    // send req.body to client
});
```

**PS:** Previously, I have used `socket.io` one time in the project: the client opens a socket, and then the server emits a message named `id`, the client receives it. In the client:

```
socket = io.connect();
socket.on('id', function (id) { ... })
```

In `www` (server):

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("LOG: just connected: " + socket.id);
  socket.emit('id', socket.id);
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log("LOG: just disconnected: " + socket.id)
  })
})
```

But I cannot imagine how to write `socket.emit` inside Expressjs routing...

**Edit 1:** I tried to do the following to send a message to all the clients but in the console, it only displayed until `before emit`, and in the client it showed `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

```
router.post('/message/sendMessage', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("router.post /message/sendMessage");
    console.log("before emit");
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("LOG: just connected: " + socket.id);
        io.emit("message", "this is a test");
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log("LOG: just disconnected: " + socket.id)
        })
    })
    console.log("after emit");
});
```

Comment: Do you have a session object for your http connection?  If so, you can put the `socket.id` in the session when the socket.io connect first connects and from then on you can get the socket.id from the session object on any http request and using the socket.id, you can get the socket which you can then to `socket.emit()` on.

Comment: Assume I could pass the id into http request, how can I get the socket from the id?

Comment: As I asked before, do you have an express session already established for the http connection?  If so, there are modules that will help you do the interconnect between http and socket.io socket.  Please answer the question about whether you have a session established already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually my question comes down to a common question: how to use socket.io inside an express routes file.

And I have found a super answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31277123/702977

So in `www`:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
app.set('socketio', io);
```

and in `index.js`:

```
router.post('/message/sendMessage', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("router.post /message/sendMessage");
    var io = req.app.get('socketio');
    io.emit("message", "hi!");
    res.json("hahaha")
});
```

If I want to send a message to a certain client, I need to pass the information like id as a parameter into router.post, and then use for example `io.to(req.body.id).emit("message", req.body.message);`

Comment: That `io.emit()` sends to ALL connected clients, not just the one making the http request.