# express + pug app, update multiple routes when txt file changes?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple express + app that consists of two views.  localhost:xxxx/ and localhost:xxxx/view  `view` simply displays a number read from a text file, the index route allows the user to increment that number, and also displays it.  These two views will be displayed in different browser tabs, and I am using Pug templates. I have the index view updating fine, but cannot figure out how to update both views when the value in the text file changes.

**Main router file**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    let data = fs.readFileSync('./data.txt', 'utf8');
    let number = parseInt(data);
    res.render('index', { number });
})

router.post('/', countController.increment);

router.get('/view', countController.readFile);
```

**Controller**

```
exports.increment = (req, res) => {
  let data = fs.readFileSync('./data.txt', 'utf8');
  let number = parseInt(data);
  number++;
  fs.writeFile('./data.txt', number, function() {
    res.render('index', { number });
  });
}

exports.readFile = (req, res) => {
  let number = fs.readFileSync('./data.txt', 'utf8');
  res.render('view', { number })
}
```

Is there a way to update both views that are running in separate browsers, or do i need to use something like socket.io?  Thanks!

Comment: The separate tabs or browsers represent two unique connections to your server, so you'll either have to use WebSockets or something like setInterval() to continually update the display.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip on websockets! This post led me in the direction to solve it, passing in socketio to my router.  [Use socket.io inside a express routes file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856190/use-socket-io-inside-a-express-routes-file)