# How to socket.broadcast.emit within an Express route handler?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

**Desired Behaviour**

I currently update a Node/Express/MongoDB app via [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) requests.

The server response is sent back to the success handler of the ajax request and various interface changes are made on the sender's client.

*Client Side*

```
function update_database(parameters) {

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/v1/my_path",
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        headers: headers,
        success: function(results) {

            // perform interface changes

        },
        statusCode: {
            500: function() {

                console.log("that didn't work");

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Ofcourse, this just updates the sender's client.

I would like to update all connected clients.

**What I've Tried**

The [official socket.io cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/) shows the relevant approach would be:

```
// send to all clients except sender
socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast', 'hello friends!');
```

In context, the `Broadcasting` section of the [official tutorial](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) shows:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.broadcast.emit('hi');
});
```

**Question**

How do I `socket.broadcast.emit` from within a route handler's function?

Do I need to wrap each `broadcase.emit` in a `io.on('connection')` callback function?

The following does not work because the variable `socket` has not been declared, but something seems "not right" about having to use the `io.on('connection')` wrapper each time I want to `socket.broadcast.emit`.

*Server Side*

```
// app setup
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

// the route handler
app.route("/api/:api_version/my_path")
    .post(api_my_post);

// the function
const api_my_post = (req, res) => {

    // define the filter and update
    var filter = { _id: o_id };
    var update = { $set: { key: value } };

    // perform the required database update
    collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {

            // create an object to return
            var response_json = { key: value, key_2: value_2 };

            // return the object to the ajax success handler
            res.json(response_json);

            // return the object to all other connected clients
            socket.broadcast.emit("ajax_response", response_json);

        }
    });

}
```

**Edit:**

The following answer looks promising and relatively simple, but only seems to cater for an `io.emit` scenario and not a `socket.broadcast.emit` scenario.

Is it possible to somehow access `socket` within a route to allow for usage of `socket.broadcast.emit`?:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31277123

*Base configuration:*

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
// next line is the money
app.set('socketio', io);
```

*Inside route or middleware:*

```
exports.foo = function(req,res){
    // now use socket.io in your routes file
    var io = req.app.get('socketio');
    io.emit('hi!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to implement socket connection only once like and pass the socket object to your controller

BoilerPlate code

```
socket_object = require('./controllers/myapp/socket.js');
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
socket_object(socket);
});
```

where socket.js will have functions like

```
module.exports = function(socket) {

socket.on('getevent', function(data) { 

});
```